# gradle-nebula create but don't push git tag

Tags: gradle, netflix-nebula-plugins, gradle-git

I am maintaining a project using **gradle** with **nebula** for release and semver. For various reasons, I want to prevent the nebula plugin (`gradle clean final`) to push the created git tag by itself and delegate this into another place in my (jenkins) pipeline. How could this be done? Is it even feasible to further use nebula for this approach or is there another gradle release plugin that gets the job done the way I would like it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a undocumented gradle property `release.disableGitChecks` however it will also [prevent from tagging the commit](https://thewaysoftech.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/managing-your-project-version-with-gradle-plugins/), too.

I solved this by using another release plugin called [axion](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin) which seems to get the job done and is configurable just as I needed it to.